# How to Efficiently Detect Schema and Configuration Changes in Apache Pulsar on K8s?

Tags: apache, message-broker, kubernetes

I'm managing an Apache Pulsar cluster deployed on a K8s cluster and we've run into a challenge that I hope to get some insights on. We're looking to establish a robust system that can promptly detect changes within our setup, specifically focusing on schemas and configurations. The ideal solution would enhance our system's responsiveness and robustness by quickly identifying and potentially responding to any modifications.

However, we're currently at a crossroads regarding the best methodologies or tools to employ. Our primary goal is to monitor:

- Changes in topic schemas that might affect producers or consumers.
- Modifications in the cluster or namespace configurations.
- Any other critical changes that should be observed in a typical Apache Pulsar setup.

I'm reaching out for recommendations on:

1. **Strategies**: What are the proven strategies for monitoring these aspects in Pulsar?
2. **Tools**: Are there specific tools or integrations that work well with Apache Pulsar to achieve this kind of monitoring?
3. **Best Practices**: If you've handled similar scenarios, what best practices or lessons learned can you share?
4. **Alerting**: How can we set up the system to not just monitor but also alert us in real-time or near-real-time of these changes?

Please note that we're open to both built-in Pulsar features that we might not be fully leveraging and external tools or systems that can be integrated efficiently.

Comment: Please note that this site is about recommending **software** – not about general recommendations on strategies, best practices etc. Can you please **[edit]** and rephrase you question to match that?